# Starting a transaction with JDBC in Clojure without a block/function

Tags: jdbc, clojure, transactions

Is it possible to start a transaction in Clojure using JDBC without having to encase the code in a block? Obviously I'd have to call another function to end the transaction later one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clojure.java.jdbc` is a wrapper around various Java implementations of db connectors. If you don't want to use `with-db-transaction` in a block you can get a connection with `get-connection`, save it in your state (e.g. an atom), then do:

`(.setAutoCommit conn false)`

then perform all the operations you want, and then

`(.commit conn)`